# Reinstall packages automatically into virtual environment after Python minor version upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I've got several virtual environments (dozens) lying on my disk made by the `venv` module of Python 3.6. Now I've upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 in a haste and only afterwards noticed that 3.6 is not available at all for Ubuntu 19.10 from the generally acknowledged sources. I've managed to upgrade the *Python versions* of these virtual environments by locating `bin/python3` under my home directory and running `python3.7 -mvenv --upgrade` on the containing folders.

Now, while `python3.7 -mvenv --upgrade` upgrades the Python in the virtual environment, it does nothing to reinstall my previous package versions in the `lib/python3.7/site-packages` under that `venv`. I guess I could have done this by installing Python 3.6, `pip freeze`ing the requirements from the `venv` and then upgrading the venv to Python 3.7, `pip install -r`ing - *if only* there was Python 3.6 install available for my new OS.

Is there any other way to do this in a rather automated fashion (perhaps mainly the `pip freeze` using the old `lib/python3.6` directory) without me having to install Python 3.6 from source, using conda or installing 3.6 from some random PPAs? I want to upgrade all environments en masse so that in the future when I need to do something with a random environment it would continue working with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your new 3.7 venv you should have `pkg_resources` available - `setuptools` is automatically installed when created. If not, just `pip install setuptools`.

`setuptools` library code is actually what `pip` is vendoring to make `pip freeze` work. But you can just freeze it manually.

```
# in 3.7 runtime...
import pkg_resources
old_site_dir = ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"
working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet([old_site_dir])
for dist in working_set:
    print(dist.as_requirement())
```

You can throw that output in a `requirements.txt` file and likely have a working reconstructed site, no `python3.6` runtime required.

Note that this method may not be 100% foolproof, because it is possible for projects to declare separate dependency trees for python3.6 and python3.7 by using *environment markers* in their distribution metadata (see [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers)). It is also possible that items installed in your 3.6 site do not support 3.7 *at all*. However it is pretty uncommon to see that in a minor version bump between 3.6 and 3.7, so just using the working set should be "good enough" in practice.

Comment: "Good enough" *is* good enough in this case. No problem in updating the odd module here and there after the bulk work has been done.